# MySQL sorting with Using temporary; Using filesort

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, query-performance

Here is the query I'm trying to launch:

```
SELECT c.creative_id, c.creative_title, c.creative_image_name, c.gravity, c.ad_strength
FROM creatives AS c
INNER JOIN term_relationships AS tr ON c.creative_id = tr.creative_id
WHERE tr.term_id
IN ( 14, 1, 50, 76, 104 )
GROUP BY c.creative_id
HAVING COUNT(tr.term_id ) =5
ORDER BY c.gravity ASC 
LIMIT 30;
```

Here is what `EXPLAIN` for this query outputs:

[image]

Here is the `creatives` table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `creatives` (
  `creative_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `scraper_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `creative_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `creative_image_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_attrib` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_image_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creative_subtext` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest_url` varchar(2083) NOT NULL,
  `lp_url` varchar(2083) NOT NULL,
  `lp_image_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lp_image_flag` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `creative_first_seen` date NOT NULL,
  `creative_last_seen` date NOT NULL,
  `daily_ad_count` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ad_strength` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prev_ad_strength` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `gravity` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`creative_id`),
  KEY `gravity` (`gravity`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=173037591 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm concerned about `Using temporary; using filesort` when launching both with `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` on another column. If I remove `ORDER BY`, the temporary and filesort go away and the query runs really fast.

What I don't understand, why mysql needs temporary table, why can't it first where filter + sort by `c.gravity`, then group by the resulting table and filter according to `HAVING` clause. The filtered table will be sorted by `c.gravity` correctly as the gravity value remains unchanged after the grouping and having filter.

What I tried:

1. Selected everything without `ORDER BY`, wrapped into a subquery and joined again on `creatives` table - same result, using temporary, filesort and slow
2. tried to add `FORCE USE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (gravity)` and it doesn't change anything. `EXPLAIN` and execution time remain the same.

**UPDATE**: the question has been answered by [@Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james) and it's really much faster with his correlated subquery and not using `GROUP BY`. I'm adding here an `EXPLAIN` output for the query:

[image]

And the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE term_relationships` with the newly created index:

[image]

And one more question to @Rick: why do we need the outer query with `c3`? It seems just to join `creatives` on its own one more just to get the values from other columns and order the records by gravity. However, they are already sorted with the inner query and we can easily add missing columns in `c1` making it:

```
SELECT  c1.creative_id,c1.creative_title,c1.creative_image_name,c1.gravity, c1.ad_strength
            FROM  creatives AS c1
            WHERE  
              ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM  term_relationships
                    WHERE  c1.creative_id = creative_id
                      AND  term_id IN ( 14, 1, 50, 76, 104 )
              ) = 5 
            ORDER BY  c1.gravity ASC
            LIMIT  30;
```

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something in your query?

Comment: (About `c3`) Without `c3`, only `creative_id` is hauled around in the tmp table.  With `c3`, lots of columns are hauled around.  If there is a big difference between the `LIMIT` (30) and the number of rows before `LIMITing`, then there could be a noticeable performance difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temp table and filesort are not the villains, per se.  It's how bulky they are.

This may look more complex, but it may be faster:

```
SELECT  c3.creative_id,
        c3.creative_title, c3.creative_image_name,
        c3.gravity, c3.ad_strength
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  creative_id
            FROM  creatives AS c1
            WHERE  
              ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM  term_relationships
                    WHERE  c1.creative_id = creative_id
                      AND  term_id IN ( 14, 1, 50, 76, 104 )
              ) = 5 
            ORDER BY  c1.gravity ASC
            LIMIT  30
      ) AS c2
    JOIN  creatives c3 USING (creative_id)
    ORDER BY  c3.gravity
```

If it happens to use `INDEX(gravity)` for the inner query, then it will stop after finding 30 rows that have all 5 transactions.  If it generates a tmp table, it will be only 30 rows -- much better than with your original query.  Note also, that the tmp table will be narrower -- only `creative_id` will be in it.  Finally it reaches back into `creatives` to get the rest of the desired columns.  Finally, there will be another sort, but with only 30 rows.

Furthermore, "filesort" is often a very fast sort in RAM, not really a "file" sort.  I'm pretty sure my query will not be on disk.

`term_relationships` needs this composite index: `INDEX(creative_id, term_id)`.

Comment: Thanks Rick, we're going to try it today. I'll let you know, at the first glance it really works fast. I'll look at your comment then too. Thanks a LOT!

Comment: update: we tested it and changed our code to use it - thanks again. BTW, very interesting way of writing a group by + count() without actually using group by! I also tried to add the index you mentioned on `terms_relationships`(creative_id, term_id) , but it's not used according to `EXPLAIN` output, so not sure if we need it for this very query.

Comment: That's a "correlated subquery" and it needs only a single count, hence no `GROUP BY`.  Let's see the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; I'm puzzled about not using that index.  Is it fast "enough" now?

Comment: see my edit of the original question after UPDATE. I have one more question - perhaps I'm wrong and the explain output after adding that index on term_relationships.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY (a,b)` and `KEY(a,b)` are redundant; the latter is virtually useless.  (I guess I did not know that you already have the PK.)